# Is it possible to compile this code?

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, compile

I'm not really familiar with the Compile function at Mathematica yet, but I know that it can, in some cases, be faster than using a non-compiled version of a code.

I've been giving some shots in compiling the code below, but haven't been succesful yet. Do you have any hint that could help me?

```
    model[n_, r_, p_] /; n >= 3 := 
 Module[{g, vdeg, el, el2, node, newnode, links, prob, x, list, 
   list2}, g = ConstantArray[{}, n];
  g[[1 ;; 5]] = Table[AdjacencyList[CycleGraph[5], j], {j, 5}];
  vdeg = ConstantArray[0, n];
  vdeg[[1 ;; 5]] = 2;
  Do[If[RandomReal[] <= p,
     (*duplication*)
     node = RandomChoice[
       N[((vdeg[[1 ;; j - 1]]^r)*(1 - 
             LocalClusteringCoefficient[
              Graph[Union[
                Map[Sort, 
                 Flatten[MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #1}] &, g], 
                  1]]]]]))] -> Range[j - 1]];
     g[[j]] = g[[node]];
     vdeg[[j]] = vdeg[[node]];

     (*mutation*)
     If[ RandomReal[] <= 0.05,
      Do[vdeg[[k]] += 1;

          g[[k]] = Append[g[[k]], j], {k, 
           Flatten[Table[Drop[g[[node]], {l}], {l, #}]]}] &@
        RandomSample[Range[Length[g[[node]]]], 
         RandomInteger[{1, Length[g[[node]]] - 1}]];
      ,
      Do[vdeg[[k]] += 1; g[[k]] = Append[g[[k]], j], {k, g[[node]]}];];
     ,
     (*de novo acquisition*)

     prob = N[vdeg[[1 ;; j - 1]]/Total[vdeg[[1 ;; j - 1]]]];
     list = 
      Do[x = Select[prob, # > RandomReal[] &]; 
       If[x != {}, Return[x], Continue[]], {1000}];
     list2 = Table[Position[prob, t], {t, #}] &@list;
     node = Flatten[Table[Extract[Range[j - 1], h], {h, #}] &@list2];
     g[[j]] = node;
     vdeg[[j]] = Length[node];
     Do[vdeg[[k]] += 1; g[[k]] = Append[g[[k]], j], {k, node}]];
   , {j, 6, n}];
  Graph[Union[
    Map[Sort, Flatten[MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #1}] &, g], 1]]]]]
```

This is a code I'm using to generate complex networks, and it has to steps:

- the new node can be a duplicate node already existing in the network, and this node will connect to the neighbors of the parent node. After that, there is a mutation step, which will remove with a probability of 0.05 random nodes created between the new node and its neighbors.
- if the new node doesn't follow the duplication process, it has a probability to connect with all the existing nodes in the network, with the condition that it has to have at least one link by the end of the process.

Comment: As a tip: if your code uses functions not in [this list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101), then it's not compilable.

Comment: Try modularizing your code, break it up into smaller functions with explicit names, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13256612/4712538) for good reasons why.  In your case, you may find that some of the smaller functions you make are compilable.  But you won't get something with `LocalClusteringCoefficient` or `Graph` to compile.

Comment: Why did you delete your recent post?